# hover function with scale jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-transit

I cant figure out whats wrong here.

I have made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/dyNxs/

It is solved by adding a a transit script for jquery. you can download one here:http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

**HTML**

```
<section class="slider-panel red-background">
    <div class="slider-caption-wrap">
        <div class="rollOver">  <span class="rollOverSymbol">x</span>
    <span class="rollOverSymbolBG"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-caption-wrap {
    background-color: #333;
    width:20%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 15%;
    left:15%;
}
.rollOver {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../img/overlayDottyDark.png") repeat scroll 0px 0px rgba(200, 57, 59, 0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.rollOverSymbol {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(148, 41, 43);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.rollOverSymbolBG {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: rgb(204, 72, 75);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".slider-caption-wrap").hover(

function () {
    $(".rollOver", this).css({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $(".rollOverSymbolBG", this).stop().transition({
        scale: 1
    }, 1400, 'easeOutCirc');
    $(".rollOverSymbol", this).stop().transition({
        scale: 1,
        rotate: '0deg'
    }, 500, 'easeOutCirc');
},

function () {
    $(".rollOverSymbolBG", this).stop().transition({
        scale: 4
    }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
    $(".rollOverSymbol", this).stop().transition({
        scale: 2,
        rotate: '-45deg'
    }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
    $(".rollOver", this).stop().transition({
        opacity: 0
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: There is no `.transition()` method in jQuery.

Comment: is their some js file you forget to embed on your fiddle? i think so...

Answer (score 0):

I think you havnt attached the `jquery.transit.js` file to the fiddle...

Working demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/dyNxs/2/